# Emacs fast navigation by character?

Tags: vim, emacs, navigation

I came across an interesting package that does fast navigation by character, but I can't find it anymore, and can't remember its name.  Apparently the idea came from vim.  There is definitely an emacswiki page for it.

Basically, you press a key to enter a minor-mode, enter a search term, and it dims the window, and sequentially highlights all occurences of the search term in the window.  Then you can press 'a' to go to the first one, 'b' for the second, etc.

Any help?

Edit: I'll add the vim tag, since the vim package name will be enough for me to find it.

Comment: Note that the built-in `M-x occur` provides parts of that functionality, as does the standard `C-s` which highlights all occurrences of the given search term and lets you cycle through the matches by typing `C-s` again, or `C-r` for backwards cycling. Also, try `C-u C-s` for regexps in the same manner.

Comment: It's all about speed.  My eyes are on where I want the point to be, I don't want to have to skip through the intervening matches.  If a match is close, then iy-go-to-char saves key strokes from isearch.

Comment: I should also add that I've reimplemented iy-go-to-char on top of isearch for
lazy match highlighting, integration with acejump, and various other
improvements.

http://github.com/lewang/jump-char

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ace-jump-mode](https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode/wiki) seems
to be what you're looking for.

> The inspiration for AceJump comes from a vim plugin called
>   [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526).
>   EasyMotion provides a much simpler way to use motions in vim. It
>   takes the  out of w or f{char} by
>   highlighting all possible choices and allowing you to press one key
>   to jump directly to the target. So I decided to write something
>   similar for Emacs.

This minor mode gives you the ability to:

- jump to a word
- jump to any characters in a word
- jump to a line

The wiki page is also available on the
[Emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump).

Comment: Could you add some more detail to this answer, beyond a link? Even though you linked to a pretty stable website, it'll help reduce the chances of link rot, and it'll improve the quality of this question for future visitors.

Comment: For a source that's independent of the GitHub repository, here's the EmacsWiki link: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump

Comment: Also in IntelliJ IDEA, there is a plugin for Acejump.  http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea_ce&pluginId=7163

Answer (score 2):

If the Vim package name will be enough: I think you're referring to [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [`iy-go-to-char.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/iy-go-to-char.el), and you probably saw it in [this EmacsRocks screencast](http://emacsrocks.com/e04.html). I uploaded it to [marmalade-repo.org](http://marmalade-repo.org) a while ago, too, which may help you if you're using package.el.

Comment: I have and use this.  But the package I saw works differently.  Instead of keeping press a key to traverse matches, you press a letter corresponding to the match you want.  Seems like it could be faster.

Comment: Aha, my mistake. I just tried `ace-jump-mode`, as @Daimrod suggested, and I think it's slower than `iy-go-to-char`: the matches are "numbered" starting at the beginning of the buffer, not the cursor location, so there will always be a delay while you read the buffer looking for the "a", "b" marker etc.

Comment: I added `iy-goto-char` a while ago, but it's not in my workflow yet.  Seems like it should be implemented on top of isearch to get the other goodies, like highlighting targets.

Comment: I've reimplemented iy-go-to-char on top of isearch for lazy match highlighting, integration with acejump, and various other improvements. Comments welcome. https://github.com/lewang/jump-char

Comment: @event_jr - nice work. Perhaps you could submit it to marmalade-repo.org?

Comment: @sanityinc: you don't look for the 'a' or 'b' marker...  You should first look at the very spot to which you want to jump and keep your eyes there: then you invoke your, say, *ace-jump-char-mode* shortcut --while still looking precisely where you want to go-- and then you enter the "marker" you see. There's no time spent "looking for markers" because your eyes are already at the correct place: that's the way to efficiently use *ace-jump-mode*.  Now there's a tiny delay to "recognize" the marker but IMHO this beats any other way to navigate on screen (unless your cursor stays on the same line)

Comment: @sanityinc: also it's precisely meant to be used to jump to something in the current view: it's not to search something in your buffer that "may or may not" be on the current view.  So the whole point of *ace-jump-mode* is that you can quickly jump to something that you know that is currently viewable because, well, you're precisely looking at it.  So it comes as an additional way to navigate around and not as something replacing all the other ways to navigate.  It's complementary and it's totally sweet : )

Comment: @TacticalCode Thanks for taking the time to comment. I'll revisit `ace-jump-mode`.

Comment: @sanityinc: event_jr also commented in another thread that there's a mode you can use that is similar to iy-go-to-char but that can then "switch" to ace-jump-mode if you want to: it's called *jump-char.el* and made by "Le Wang" (which, I think, is *event_jr* but I may be mistaken on that).  I didn't take the time to look into that one yet but it looks interesting: it would combine a more traditional search with *ace-jump-mode*.  But yeah: give *ace-jump-mode* another try and first look where you want to go then call it: I assigned *M-e* to *ace-jump-char-mode* and it's fffaaasssttt : )

Comment: @TacticalCoder Yep, discovered that yesterday and I'm using that too now. Thanks for the pointers.